# Running Multiple Stored Procedures in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am creating a SQL script file in MySQL. The script simply creates a table and some stored procedures. I have two questions.

1. I need to check if table exists, skip the create table statement.
   But if procedure exists, drop it and then create a new one. Here is
   the code I am trying -

   ```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student (   
       Id INT PRIMARY KEY,   Name
       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
   );

   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_StudentInsert;

   DELIMITER $$
   CREATE PROCEDURE usp_StudentInsert(
       id INT, 
       name VARCHAR(100)) 
   BEGIN    
       INSERT INTO Student(Id, Name) VALUES(id, name); 
   END$$

   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_StudentRetrieve;

   DELIMITER $$ 
   CREATE PROCEDURE usp_StudentRetrieve(studentId INT)
   BEGIN
       SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Id = studentId;
   END$$
   ```

   There is an error "SQL Syntax Error near DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS
   usp_StudentRetrieve";
2. What is best way to execute script file using PHP code?

Thank you in advanced.

Ritesh

PS - I am using MySQL Workbench V5.2 with MySQL 5.1, if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a space after delimiter and it works for me:

from `delimiter$$` to `delimiter $$`

```
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE usp_StudentInsert(id INT,name VARCHAR(100)) 
    -> BEGIN
    ->  INSERT INTO Student(Id, Name) VALUES(id, name); 
    -> END
    -> $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> drop procedure usp_studentinsert;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT:

```
mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_StudentInsert;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Tried this but still same error. "SQL Syntax Error near DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_StudentRetrieve."

Comment: are you changing the delimiter again after created the SP? add space after end and $$

Comment: Changing delimiter? What do you mean? Sorry, but I am new to MySQL. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: look my example. after I create the procedure I execute `delimiter ;` that's to return `;` as end of line

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I don't know why it is complex. It might look complex to me since I use SQL Server. BTW, can you answer my second question too?